# VBA run Unix command get run time error 5

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to let VBA to create a folder on a server. The below code works fine:

```
Public pUser As String
Public pPass As String
Public pHost As String
Public cmd2 As Variant

Sub PlinkUserInfo()
Const cstrSftp1 As String = "C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY\plink.exe"
pUser = InputBox("Please enter your Putty username")
pPass = InputBox("Please enter your Putty password")
pHost = Workbooks("Robot Model.xlsm").Worksheets("Preparation").Range("C6").Value
pCommand = "cd /busbank/home; mkdir test3"
cmd2 = cstrSftp1 & " -l " & pUser & " -pw " & pPass & " -P 22 -2 -ssh " & pHost & " " & pCommand
Dim waitOnReturn As Boolean: waitOnReturn = True
Dim windowStlye As Integer: windowStyle = 1
Debug.Print cmd2
Call Shell(cmd2, vbNormalFocus)
End Sub
```

However, I want to break this code into two parts, and call them separately from another macro, as follows:

```
Public pUser As String
Public pPass As String
Public pHost As String
Public cmd2 As Variant

Sub PlinkUserInfo()
Const cstrSftp1 As String = "C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY\plink.exe"
pUser = InputBox("Please enter your Putty username")
pPass = InputBox("Please enter your Putty password")
pHost = Workbooks("Robot Model.xlsm").Worksheets("Preparation").Range("C6").Value
End Sub

Sub PlinkRunCommand()
cmd2 = cstrSftp1 & " -l " & pUser & " -pw " & pPass & " -P 22 -2 -ssh " & pHost & " " & pCommand
Dim waitOnReturn As Boolean: waitOnReturn = True
Dim windowStlye As Integer: windowStyle = 1
Debug.Print cmd2
Call Shell(cmd2, vbNormalFocus)
End Sub

Public pCommand As Variant

Sub SetUpRemoteFolder()
Call PlinkUserInfo
pCommand = "cd /busbank/home; mkdir test3"
Call PlinkRunCommand
MsgBox ("The server folder is successfully created.")
End Sub
```

Call Shell part gives me run time error 5, Invalid procedure call or argument. Anyone knows why??

Comment: you didn't quote your path, so it's trying to run a program named `c:\program`, with arguments `files (x86)\putty\plink.exe`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You define cstrSftp1 in PlinkUserInfo(), and use it in PlinkRunCommand(), but its private in PlinkUserInfo, therefore not defined in PlinkRunCommand. Then you try to call Shell without real path, just the parameters.

If you use "option explicit" you have to define every variable and would get an error message in this case.